# syntax for sql request with jinja template

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

In apache superset, my virtual dataset has this code :

```
select * from portna
where region like ({{ '%' }}+{{ filter_values('region') }}+{{ '%' }})
```

But when i try to put nd in the filter 'region', he answers :

Error: syntax error at or near "nd" LINE 6: where region like '%['nd']%') AS virtual_table

I don't understand

I would like Superset to show all the regions with "nd" in the name.
I want :

```
select * from portna
where region ilike '%nd%'
```

where nd is the filter_values('region')

Thank you

Comment: If you receive `['nd']` as an answer, this means the return is a list, so you are probably interested in the first element of the list: `{{ filter_values('region') | first }}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try but it seems difficult.